# Js Script not working in NextJs Class Problem

Tags: javascript, class, next.js

I have an FAQ page on the website I am building right now. I got the faq section from a template. I tried to use Javascript within my NextJs Projekt but it is not working.

```js
var faq = document.getElementsByClassName("faqpage");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < faq.length; i++) {
    faq[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
        to highlight the button that controls the panel */
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        

        /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
        var body = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (body.style.display === "block") {
            body.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            body.style.display = "block";
        }
    }); 
}
var cpt = document.getElementsByClassName("faqbody");
var i; 

for (i = 0; i < faq.length; i++) {
    cpt[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
        to highlight the button that controls the panel */
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        

        /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
        var body = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (body.style.display === "block") {
            body.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            body.style.display = "block";
            
        }
    }); 
}
```

```css
.Faq {
      background-color: rgba(46,40,35,255); 
      padding-top: 50px;
      padding-bottom: 150px;
}
.Faq h2 {
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 4vh;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.faqcontainer{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      }
      .hrline{
        width: 62%;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }
      .faqpage {
          cursor: pointer;
          padding: 30px 20px;
          width: 60%;
          border: none;
          font-size: 25px;
          font-weight: 600; 
          outline: none;
          transition: 0.4s;
          margin: auto;
          color: #EC2628;
      }

      .faqbody{
            margin: auto;
            /* text-align: center; */
            width: 50%;
            line-height: 30px;
            font-size: 20px; 
            padding: 0 18px; 
            display: none;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
      }
  .faqpage:after {
      content: '\002B';
      /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
      font-size: 35px;
      font-weight: 100;
      color: white;
      
      float: right;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
  }
  .active:after {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
      font-weight: 100; 
  }
```

```html
<div className={styles.Faq}>

                        <h2>FAQ</h2>

                        <div className={styles.faqone}>                 
                              <h1 className={styles.faqpage}>How can I join the community?</h1>
                              <div className={styles.faqbody}>
                                    <p>We have a very active community and we welcome new members with open arms! Come and chat with us on Discord.</p>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr className={styles.hrline}/>
                        <div className={styles.faqtwo}>                 
                              <h1 className={styles.faqpage}>How can I join the community?</h1>
                              <div className={styles.faqbody}>
                                    <p>We have a very active community and we welcome new members with open arms! Come and chat with us on Discord.</p>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr className={styles.hrline}/>
                        <div className={styles.faqthree}>                 
                              <h1 className={styles.faqpage}>How can I join the community?</h1>
                              <div className={styles.faqbody}>
                                    <p>We have a very active community and we welcome new members with open arms! Come and chat with us on Discord.</p>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr className={styles.hrline}/>
                        <div className={styles.faqfour}>                 
                              <h1 className={styles.faqpage}>How can I join the community?</h1>
                              <div className={styles.faqbody}>
                                    <p>We have a very active community and we welcome new members with open arms! Come and chat with us on Discord.</p>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr className={styles.hrline}/>

                        <Script src="../components/FAQLOC.js"></Script>
                  </div>
```

I thought it  has something to do with the classes and that javascript cannot grab the classes from nextjs but I also don't know how to solve this problem.

The Snippet is so that you can see all of my CODE!
Can someone help me?

Comment: Why are you doing hand-rolled DOM manipulation in a React app? That is almost certainly going to screw things up, even if you fix the SSR issue.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm really new to NextJs so I need to figure out how everything works. What can you recommend to do?

Comment: Start with create-react-app and some React tutorials. Then, once you understand React, move to next.js with create-next-app. The next.js docs are going to all assume that you already know React.

Comment: @JaredSmith Okay good to know. I know Javascript, Html, CSS, and Solidity and somehow thought I can start with NextJs and learn React on the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Components on Nextjs are all server-side by default so you don't have access to the document object. Have you tried importing your component dynamically and setting SSR to false? https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

Comment: This should *arguably* be a comment rather than an answer, but it's also probably the source of (one of) the OP's problems. +1 but do try to have a bit more of an authoritative style in your answers.